# Responsive fluid property table html implementation

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design, responsive

I have property table that I need to look different for desktop and mobile applications.

Desktop - 1 table:

```
         | Product1 | Product2
Property | Value    | Value
Property | Value    | Value
```

Mobile - 2 tables:

```
         | Product1
Property | Value  
Property | Value
```

```
         | Product2
Property | Value   
Property | Value
```

All tables should be `width: 100%`. I'm looking for the solution to reuse the same html layout for both viewports, just change styles for different screen width.

I tried flex box, but I'm not sure how to make cell heights to be the same for the first combined table. All cells should stretch if 1 cell have 2 lines of text.

What is the best way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this to include all possible tables and not showing tables prepared for mobile while screen size is big, and not showing tables prepared for desktop while having small screen sizes.

example;
html

```
<table class="propertyTable">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>product 1</td>
      <td>product 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>property</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table class="propertyTableMobile">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>product 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>property</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>property</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table  class="propertyTableMobile">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>product 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>property</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>property</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

css

```
.propertyTable{
 width: 100%;
 }

.propertyTable td,.propertyTableMobile td{
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 }
.propertyTableMobile{
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
 .propertyTable{
 display: none;
 }
 .propertyTableMobile{
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly my current implementation, but I'm looking for the solution to reuse the same html layout for both viewports, just change styles for different screen width.